# Could not cast value of type 'AVPlayer' to 'Swift.AnyObject.Type'

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using swift 3, the code compiles, but when I execute it breaks on the first line with a signal SIGABRT and gives me that error message:

```
if (object as AnyObject).isKind(of: AVPlayer() as Any as! AnyClass) {
        switch keyPath {
            case "status":
                if let value = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Int, let itemStatus = AVPlayerItemStatus(rawValue: value) {
                    if itemStatus == .readyToPlay {
                        status = .playing
                        notifyOnPlayBegins()
                    } else if itemStatus == .failed {
                        let error = player?.currentItem?.error
                        print("AVPlayerItem status: \(itemStatus)\nError: \(error)")
                        status = .stopped
                        notifyError(error as! NSError)
                    }
                }
            break
```

AVPlayer:

`open class AVPlayer : NSObject`

Comment: which type of `object` declaration

Comment: check out the answer and let me know if you have any confusion..

Comment: `object : Any?`

Comment: AnyObject doesn't have a member called isKind(of:). What are you trying to achieve with this check? If it is simply to check whether object is an AVPlayer = if object is AVPlayer {  } would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Foundation

class AVPlayer : NSObject {

}

let object : Any? = AVPlayer()

if object is AVPlayer {
    print( "Meow" )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out it will help you.

**You can check the object type by three ways:**

```
let object:Any?
object = AVPlayer()

if let player = object as? AVPlayer {
    print("true")
}
if (object!).isKind(of: AVPlayer.self) {
    print("true")
}
if object is AVPlayer {
    print("true")
}
```

Comment: It doesn't´t compile, if I write `guard let keyPath = keyPath, let object = AVPlayer(), let change = change else { return }`, it says me "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type not AVPlayer"

Comment: You can't  write `let object = AVPlayer()` because we do typecast not iniatialization..!!!

Comment: Given you're doing conditional typecasting with `as?`, you don't need to use `isKind(of:)` (and using `classForCoder()` is not really correct there; you should use `AVPlayer.self` instead).